# How do I find the Index of the smallest number in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have group of  numbers. Without using methods, how to pick the index of the smallest number in JavaScript? Explain, how the code will work.

```
let numbers = [20, 90, 10, 324, 9, 73] //Example array of numbers.
```

Comment: Smallest index of the smallest number? You mean smallest number index? Please provide example input/output and what you already tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barebones, without methods:

```js
let numbers = [20, 90, 10, 324, 9, 73]
let smallest = 0

for (i in numbers) {
  if (numbers[smallest] > numbers[i]) smallest = i
}

console.log(smallest)
```

First, we make a variable "smallest" and set it to 0, which is the first index of the array. Then, we go through the entire array and see if there's a number smaller than `numbers[smallest]`, the initial value of which is 0. If there is, each time `smallest` is set to the index of that smaller number.
By the end of the array, we have the variable `smallest` set to the index of the smallest number in the array. That's the solution without methods.

Using array methods and the Math library:

```js
let numbers = [20, 90, 10, 324, 9, 73]
let smallest = numbers.indexOf(Math.min(...numbers))

console.log(smallest)
```

- `Math.min()` takes a list of numbers and returns the smallest.
- `...numbers` is what's called "spreading". `Math.min()` takes parameters, not an array, (`Math.min(1, 2, 3)` not `Math.min([1, 2, 3]`). So `...numbers` turns `[20, 90, 10, 324, 9, 73]` into `(20, 90, 10, 324, 9, 73)`
- The `.indexOf()` method takes a value and finds the index of that value in an array.

Comment: Instead of setting smallest = 0, just set smallest = numbers[0] and replace it if a lesser value if encountered. This will eliminate the negative numbers problem.

Comment: Can't see why it'd produce wrong results with negative numbers. Can you provide an example? My tests with negative numbers provided correct results.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I really appreciate that

Comment: No problem! If a post answers what you were looking for, don't forget to accept it as a correct answer :)

Comment: how if there are multiple minimum value in set of array. can we get the multiple index  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the smallest number first

```
let numbers = [20, 90, 10, 324, 9, 73];
let smallest = Math.min(...numbers);
```

Then, you can get its index easily using the indexOf function.

```
let index = numbers.indexOf(smallest);
```

Comment: thank toy a lot but I'm learning  and i want to know how it's work without using something like indexOf i could easily use it, Thx <3